# How do you open a cmd file through a batch file but the command prompt application is renamed

Tags: batch-file

This sounds confusing and is possibly answered but how can you run a batch file that opens a new command prompt application and does `start ping %IP% -t` but the new command prompt application is named something else like Ip Pinger

Example:

```
:Console
start ping %IP% -t
```

^^^^This line of code opens a command prompt named, "Command prompt" but how do I rename that through the batch file that originaly opened the command prompt.

I have tried `start ping %IP% -t && title Ip pinger` but that code has not worked either and just ended up renaming the batch file application not the command prompt application.

**Simplified speaking**

You run your batch file, you insert the Ip address (which is %IP%) then you press enter and it makes a new command prompt application and it is named C:/System32/PING.EXE how do I title it using the code block it started with, without changing the name of the exe itself, like this command, `start ping %IP% -t && title Ip pinger` "start ping %IP% -t" opens the command prompt and "&& title Ip pinger" **renames the batch file not the command prompt application,** **which is the problem.**

Comment: [give the process a title](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you failed to respond to [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan)'s comment, *(made 5½ hours before your edit)*, I have expanded on it using the information from his provided link, *(also available when entering `start /?` at the Command Prompt)*.

```dos
Start "IP Pinger" Ping -t %IP%
```